# How to ensure a period between two messages over a Serial port

Tags: c#, .net, events, serial-port, buffer

The [documentation for the Serial Port](http://bit.ly/ymrmT0) states that:

> The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte
>   received. Use the BytesToRead property to determine how much data is
>   left to be read in the buffer.

The protocol we are trying to implement, separates the messages by idle periods. Since we have to rely on the time of each character received, this .NET's restriction seems to be a problem.

Does anyone know how does the .NET's SerialPort decides whether to raise an event or not. Is it to avoid the event spamming in high baud rates, so it buffers them?

Is there any guarantee that at least one event will be raised in ever XY milliseconds? What is that minimal period, if any?

How to approach this problem?

**EDIT**: A little more research shows that it can be done by setting the timeouts. Stupid me!

Comment: Simply use a for loop with a sleep call. Check if there are bytes to read and keep track of timing to get message boundary detection. Use some high precision sleep though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good plan for a protocol, unless the periods between messages are at least a couple of seconds. Windows does not provide any kind of service guarantee for code that runs in user mode, it is not a real-time operating system. Your code will fail when the machine gets heavily loaded and your code gets pre-empted by other threads that run with a higher priority.  Like kernel threads. Delays of hundreds of milliseconds are common, several seconds is certainly quite possible, especially when your code got paged-out and the paging file got fragmented.  Very hard to troubleshoot, it repeats horribly poorly.

The alternative is simple, just use a frame around the message so you can reliably detect the start and the end of a message. Two bytes will do, STX and ETX are popular choices. Add a length byte if the end-of-message byte can also appear in the data.